# Discard Element in an Array, is splice the answer?

Tags: javascript

```
/*

***If all the elements match, it should return an empty array.

***If an empty array is passed in, it should return an empty 
array.

*/



function removeElement(array, discarder) {

  if(array.length === 0) {
    array = [];
  }

  for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    if(discarder === array[i]) {
      array.splice(i, 1);
    }



    return array;
  }
}

var output = removeElement([1, 2, 3, 2, 1], 2);
console.log(output); // --> [1, 3, 1]
```

Does anyone know how I can delete an array element I specify in the discarder argument?

Also, I need to return an empty Array if all elements are the same. I've been stuck on this for way too long.

Comment: return array.filter(item => item!==discarder)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function removeElement(array, discarder) {

  if(array.length === 0) {
    return array;
  }

  return array.filter(item => item !== discarder);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Array.filter](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjEgJ77r63vAhVPAHIKHSMUAvUQFjAAegQIBxAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Ffilter&usg=AOvVaw3uj9Eml6lq1L49hIcVb04R)

```js
const removeElement = (array, discarder) => array.filter(value => value !== discarder);

var output = removeElement([1, 2, 3, 2, 1], 2);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

- Use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). No other checks needed
- Additionally you could [destructure your param](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to make your function accept more than one discarder - and use [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
const removeElement = (arr, ...rem) => arr.filter(x => !rem.includes(x));

console.log(removeElement([], 2));                    // []
console.log(removeElement([1, 2, 3, 2, 1], 2));       // [1,3,1]
console.log(removeElement([1, 2, 3, 2, 1], 2, 3));    // [1,1]
console.log(removeElement([1, 2, 3, 2, 1], 2, 3, 1)); // []
```

Answer (score 0):

Using splice, this would work:

```js
function removeItemFirst(arr, value) {
  var index = arr.indexOf(value);
  if (index > -1) {
    arr.splice(index, 1);
  }
  return arr;
}

function removeItemAll(arr, value) {
  var i = 0;
  while (i < arr.length) {
    if (arr[i] === value) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    } else {
      ++i;
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

But better way is to use `.filter()` as mentioned in @Shuvo's answer.